# Javascript: play() and pause() html video not work with mouseover

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I need to toggle video playback whenever the cursor enters and leaves a video element.

I currently use the `play()` and `pause()` methods on my video elements, but it always seems to be and undefined property.

Here's my script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

     for (i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
        video[i].addEventListener( 'mouseover', function(e) { 
             video[i].play()
        })
        video[i].addEventListener( 'mouseout', function(e) {
             video[i].pause()
        })
    }
}
```

And the HTML too:

```
<video class="myclass" loop>
    <source src="assets/images/shoes.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

The `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are firing as expected but the `play()` and `pause()` still get an undefined result in the console as you can see in the snippet below.

Can anyone please help me to fix it? Please don't give me a jQuery based method cause I'm not using jQuery.

Thanks!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

  for (i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
    video[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      video[i].play()
    })
    video[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
      video[i].pause()
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<video class="cav-sl-heros-canvas-video" loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: Change `for (i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {` to `for (let i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {` and let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks! it work for this snippets, but when i put `let` in to my script, that stop gulp process. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to resolve this is to control the video element via the mouse `event` passed to the event handler like so:

```
video[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  const mouseOverVideo = e.currentTarget;
  mouseOverVideo.play()
})
```

This approach guarantees that you'll be calling `play()` and `pause()` on the video element corresponding to the mouse events:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

  for (i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
    
    // Aquire video element via currentTarget, so that
    // call to play() is on video inside event handler's
    // closure
    video[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      var mouseOverVideo = e.currentTarget;
      mouseOverVideo.play()
    })
    
    // Aquire video element via currentTarget, so that
    // call to pause() is on video inside event handler's
    // closure
    video[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
      var mouseOverVideo = e.currentTarget;
      mouseOverVideo.pause()
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<video class="cav-sl-heros-canvas-video" loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
<video class="cav-sl-heros-canvas-video" loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: Your snippet work like a prince, but I can't use `const` or `let`, because I don't know why but it break my gulp-uglify. That is my bad I though. But you explain me so well, so thank you man, appreciate it.

Comment: @Rafv you're welcome glad I could help - just updated the answer to use `var` instead. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your time Denny, it work as aspected! Thank you so much man!

Comment: I mark your answer as accepted answer, because it work in all condition. Thanks deny, have a good time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this`. And log shows the real `i`. That's why `let` would work while `var` not.

And the difference between `let` and `var`, there is a lot of repeated questions and answers, you can search and know something about that.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

  for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
    video[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      console.log('current i', i)
      this.play()
    })
    video[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
      console.log('current i', i)
      this.pause()
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<video class="cav-sl-heros-canvas-video" loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: Worked! And thanks man , you make it so simples. Appreciate it